# Global Label style not being applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add a global implicit style to all of my labels. I've defined the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have tried putting it in the App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                        <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!--Merge Dictionaries...-->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything. I have also tried to include it in one of my theme files, but it also doesn't work. I tried doing it in a fresh project to see if there were any conflicts with different styles in my current project, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: the style is not implicit, since it has `x:Key="LabelStyle"`

Comment: @ASh my terminology might not be on point, what I meant is that it should apply itself implicitly.

Comment: What Ash meant was remove the `x:Key` attribute from the style, only then it becomes an implicit style otherwise, it is expected to be explicitly defined hence `x:Key`. And bear in mind that Labels in a `DataTemplate` will not have that style applied as they are not part of VisualTree until run-time. Also Labels are heavy weight UI elements, consider light weight `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Viewbox which do not have the Background Property. You are overwriting template and then we do not see the background of the label. I will put viewbox inside the Border where I will put color.

```
<Border Background="Green">
    <Viewbox.../>
</Border>
```

Let me know if solution works.